# Identify the element with a given text using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the below element on a webpage I am trying to scrape.

```
<a href="http://www.mylink/?p=20391">Sup Bonds Result June 26, 2018</a>
```

Below is the code that I am trying to use but doesn't seem to be working although the value exists. It worked for initial few instances but then isn't providing any result.

```
try:
    element=driver.find_element_by_partial_text('Sup Bonds Result June 26, 2018')

except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.quit()
```

below is the error that i Received, I have already used the time.sleep o allow sometime for the script to locate the element.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sup Bonds Result June 26, 2018"}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try: 
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sup Bonds Result June 26, 2018")))
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

Also note that if you want to use search by link text (partial link text) you need to pass text exactly as it **appears on page in browser**, but not as it appears in page source. So if it looks on page like `"SUP BONDS..."` you need to use the same in code

Comment: Thanks Anderson for the help.. Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were pretty close. As you are simply trying to *locate* (**not clicking**) the element, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of the element* as follows:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Sup Bonds Result June 26, 2018"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Comment: Thanks Debanjan... This works as well but am unable to mark two answers.